# Struct fields from cell array

Tags: matlab

Say I have a cell array:

```
my_cell_array = {'Jimmy', 'Timothy', 'Charles', ...}
```

Is there a compact way of defining a single `struct` that has the items of `my_cell_array` as fieldnames? The members of the new struct can hold empty cells or empty arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`cell2struct`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/cell2struct.html) is probably what you need.

```
my_cell_array = {'Jimmy', 'Timothy', 'Charles'}
s = cell2struct(cell(size(my_cell_array)), my_cell_array, 2)
s = 

      Jimmy: []
    Timothy: []
    Charles: []
```

Comment: I looked into it, but `cell2struct` seems to be designed to build `struct` **arrays** from `cell` **arrays**. What I want is a single `struct` with field names from the `cell` array. That said, you are probably right, there is probably a way of doing this with `cell2struct`. I'll look deeper into it.

Comment: Got it. Yes, thanks! I'll accept this as soon as it lets me do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this statement:

```
cell2struct(cell(size(my_cell_array)),my_cell_array,2)
```

It returns:

```
ans = 

      Jimmy: []
    Timothy: []
    Charles: []
```